# Does a non-empty message body in a "status 404" packet violate REST principles?

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404

I was talking with a co-worker that for some reason wrote a framework from the ground up just because it wasn't able to automatically unmarshall a message body on a 404 HTTP Packet.

He says that he's following REST principles. My guess is that a message body on a 404 HTTP Packet violate those principles, but I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you use a web browser to go to http://www.google.com/unknown  You will get a 404 status code and an entity body.

It is quite common for entity bodies to be returned with 404s.

If you look at the description of 400 errors in the [HTTPbis spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-12#page-28) you will see

> the server SHOULD include a
> representation containing an
> explanation of the error situation,
> and whether it is a temporary or
> permanent condition.

Comment: Huum, good to know that. But, wasn't it better to just return an URI to a error page within the header?

Comment: @Paulo  Apparently the authors of the HTTP spec didn't think so.  Why do two round trips when you only need one?  Plus you would need to include all context sensitive error information in the URI.

Comment: `http://www.google.com/unknown` does not return entity body anymore but returns html