# Server returns 404 for a web page, but page is showing fine in browser - why?

Tags: http, browser, http-status-code-404

A strange web page crossed my way. (And being a developer I have to solve the mystery.)

When accessing the web page in any browser, all seems normal. The web page is displayed as expected.

But when looking in the console the server acually returns a 404 status code:

[image]

So why is the browser rendering a page?

Looking at the Body shows valid HTML is returned:

[image]

Hold on. Responding 404 and sending the HTML along the way? And the browser renders it??

Why is this happening? Is this some server misconfiguration? Or is something clever going on here that I don't understand? Is there a practical reason for configuring a server on purpose to behave like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Another answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940737/56658)  contains some interesting information: A HTTP status code of 404 plus HTML response body is actually recommended by the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-12#page-27).

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the
> client seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD
> request, **the server SHOULD include a representation containing an
>
> explanation of the error situation**, and whether it is a temporary or
> permanent condition.  These status codes are applicable to any
> request method.  User agents SHOULD display any included
> representation to the user.

This leaves me with two possible explanations:

**Explanation 1: it's a server error.**

- the server *wrongly* returns a 404 status code
- the browser thinks the response body contains details about the error and displays it - for the end user this is the actual page

**Explanation 2: it's done on purpose to defeat crawlers and page watchers.**

- the server returns 404 on purpose - non-browser user agents won't process the result as they interpret it as error
- browsers are unaffected, the end user doesn't care as long as the page is being displayed

The second one would indeed be kind of clever if you don't want your page to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same situation. My portal was hosted in a tomcat server. The portal was loaded when the host name along with the tomcat directory path was hit. But on loading the the webpage redirected to a deep-link URL and rendered the page. But if you hit the deep link URL directly in the browser it would give you 404 error in the network tab in Dev tools although the webpage would be rendered fine.
This happens because there is no resource as your deep-link URL anywhere in your server config files, so when it searches for the resource it doesn't find one and returns 404 in the network tab in Dev tools.
But browser behaves differently with the resource URL. It first loads and connects to the host name of the resource, when returned with success gets redirected as per the config files settings and renders the deep-link URL resource HTML, styling contents properly.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't know whether this issue comes from me not being strict enough in the **.htaccess** or my CMS.

In my contrived **.htaccess** example I had the following rules to ignore these directories from being handled by the CMS.

`RewriteCond $1 !^(branch|css|js|html|images) [NC]`

I also had a **branches** directory inside my CMS' templates (created within CMS).  I guess my **.htaccess** rule wasn't strict enough here.  I had to change `branch` to `branch\/`, like so:

`RewriteCond $1 !^(branch\/|css|js|html|images) [NC]`

Only then would the page load *without* the 404 in the console.