# Exception in Tkinter callback when trying to use pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pytube

When trying to use a video downloader I made I keep getting an error stating as such.
I have looked at quite a bit of other questions trying to find a solution but its almost like I'm the only one having this issue

attached are both the error and my code

```
   import pytube
   import tkinter
   from tkinter import *
   from pytube import YouTube
   
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry('500x300')
   root.resizable(0,0)
   root.title("DataFlair-youtube video downloader")
   
   
   Label(root,text = 'Youtube Video Downloader', font ='arial 20 bold').pack()
   
   link = StringVar()
   
   Label(root, text = 'Paste Link Here:', font = 'arial 15 bold').place(x= 160 , y = 60)
   link_enter = Entry(root, width = 70,textvariable = link).place(x = 32, y = 90)
   
   
   def Downloader():
        
       url =YouTube(str(link.get()))
       video = url.streams.first()
       video.download()
       Label(root, text = 'DOWNLOADED', font = 'arial 15').place(x= 180 , y = 210)  
   
   
   Button(root,text = 'DOWNLOAD', font = 'arial 15 bold' ,bg = 'pale violet red', padx = 2, command = Downloader).place(x=180 ,y = 150)
   
   
   
   root.mainloop()
```

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)   File "c:\Users\Owner\Downloads\youtube_download.py", line 22, in Downloader
        url =YouTube(str(link.get()))   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
        self.prefetch()   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
        self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
        return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
        return urlopen(request)  # nosec   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
        response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
        response = self.parent.error(   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
        return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
        response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
        response = self.parent.error(   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Try printing `str(link.get())`. Is it the correct link? What does `YouTube(...)` expect?

Comment: It seems to be getting the right link so I'm not sure what could be happening

Comment: It looks like you're getting a 404. That means, there's nothing wrong with the code, you're just giving an invalid URL.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293044/server-returns-404-for-a-web-page-but-page-is-showing-fine-in-browser-why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614883/pytube-givng-an-http-error-404-not-found-error-anyone-knows-how-to-fix-this

Comment: use `print()` to see `str(link.get())` and check it manually in web browser. Link may look OK but it still can be wrong. Maybe server doesn't have this address. You could also show this link in question - so we could test code with this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have been facing the same issue with `pytube`. You may want to check here for solutions. [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614883/pytube-givng-an-http-error-404-not-found-error-anyone-knows-how-to-fix-this?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I get error `404` when I run with `Pytube` `10.8.3` but it works with the newest `10.8.5`

Simply `YouTube` sometimes makes changes on page and `PyTube` may need also updates.